# Validating The Login Credentials using Data Driven Frame Work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, testautomationfx

Hi I am trying to validate the credentials for the multiple users using the Selenium WebDriver.
Lets take Gmail as Example.

All User and Password information are saved in the Excel file.

Problem:

say for user 1 - I am entering the valid user name and valid password then the gmail home page is displayed .(able to login and Logout )--Test is Pass ..

For user 2-I have entered wrong credentials in the excel file , but in this case error I am getting the error Unable to locate the element .

as the user was not logged in and the code is pointing to element which will appear only after the user logs in .

Now for this I tried checking the element with class "erro_msg" which appears iff the user enters the wrong credentials .

I tried to check if the element is invisible then continue login and if it gets visible sysout the "Invalid Credential message"

"Now as of this the code works fine for valid credentials and logs out and for Invalid credentials it     stops the execution with message -Invalid credentials , now I am getting exception because the in the above case the element is visible due to wrong credentials , and thus in exception it displays waiting for element to disappear "  So I need to ask is there a prompt way to implement this ?
So from the list of 10 credentials in the excel file , if few are wrong credentials I dont want code to stop execution but to capture Invalid Credentials and continue trying for other users .

Comment: the Above is resolved , instead of catching the exception if directly execute finally, then the code validates all credentials.




        public static Boolean isElementPresent(){

  Boolean f=false;

  try{

   WebDriverWait WT=new WebDriverWait(wd, 10L);
   
f=WT.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector([class=\"error-msg\"]")));

   return f;

  }

  finally{

   return f;

  }
  
Although if there is any other alternatives please post help me to better my code

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this.  Remember that after you log in, typically the page will reload and you'll either be back on the login screen or on the default screen.  That means that you can...

1. Look at the URL instead of looking for an element.  You can either assert the url.contains("pageName you're looking for"); or log it somewhere if you don't want to halt the test due to failed assert.
2. Create an extension method that allows you to do a .Exists() an element (different than displayed).  To do that, you'll need to catch the element not found exception and return something else like null.  Then running .Exists() will return true if the element is not null. False otherwise.  [Example in C#](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/08/webdriver-iwebelementexists.html)